# Should a logging framework really swallow logging failures?

Tags: logging

While there's no doubt that a logger should not cause an application to crash, while I was bugfixing my company logger I was uncertain how to properly swallow an exception thrown by the logging framework itself. In metacode:

```
public void write(TMessage message)
{
    try
    {
        writeUnsafely(message);
    }
    catch(Exception loggingException)
    {
        // what should I do here?
    }
}
```

Should I ignore the loggingException (like log4net does) or should I let the client code choose how to handle it (maybe with a configurable handler)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NLog has a configuration option that allows logging to be configured to throw exceptions (or not):

https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file

(See the Troubleshoot Logging section).

It seems that giving the client code a chance to handle it is a reasonable choice.  A recommendation for how a client program should handle the exception might be good to include in your documentation (if you choose to implement such a capability).  An example might be something like "You can catch the LoggingException in your application's unhandled exception handler."

Comment: Thanks, your link really convinced to let the internal exception handler be configurable by the client. It seems that log4net also has something like that: http://haacked.com/archive/2006/09/27/Log4Net_Troubleshooting.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It's completely up to you, but whatever you decide, document it. Aside from adding complexity in both the code and for the users, I see no harm in making it configurable.

You could instead just write perfect code that has no bugs and never throws any exceptions. `;-)`

Comment: if it's optional, the added complexity is minimal ;) And I hope it will never be needed... it's "just in case" :D